# jQuery Traversing - how to get the right element

Tags: jquery, jquery-traversing

Here is my html code. for a lot of reasons this cannot change:

```
<ul class="menu">
<li>About Us
    <div class="menuHover">
        <ul class="left">
            <li class="item"><a href="#" title="Link">Link</a>
                <span class="m-desc">
                    <img src="../home.png" width="65" height="60" />
                    <p>This is a description: One</p>
                </span>
            </li>
            <li class="item"><a href="#" title="Link">Link</a>
                <span class="m-desc">
                    <img src="../home.png" width="65" height="60" />
                    <p>This is a description: Two</p>
                </span>
            </li>
            <li class="item"><a href="#" title="Link">Link</a>
                <span class="m-desc">
                    <img src="../home.png" width="65" height="60" />
                    <p>This is a description: Three</p>
                </span>
            </li>
            <li class="item"><a href="#" title="Link">Link</a>
                <span class="m-desc">
                    <img src="../home.png" width="65" height="60" />
                    <p>This is a description: Four</p>
                </span>
            </li>
        </ul>
                    <img src="images/dottedline.png" width="3" height="120" />
                        <div class="right">
                            <img src="images/home.png" width="65" height="60" />
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing consectetur adipi Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur</p>
            </div>
    </div>
</li>                   
<li>Contact
    <div class="menuHover">
        <ul class="left">
            <li class="item"><a href="#" title="Link">Link</a>
                <span class="m-desc">
                    <img src="../home.png" width="65" height="60" />
                    <p>This is a description: One</p>
                </span>
            </li>
            <li class="item"><a href="#" title="Link">Link</a>
                <span class="m-desc">
                    <img src="../home.png" width="65" height="60" />
                    <p>This is a description: Two</p>
                </span>
            </li>
            <li class="item"><a href="#" title="Link">Link</a>
                <span class="m-desc">
                    <img src="../home.png" width="65" height="60" />
                    <p>This is a description: Three</p>
                </span>
            </li>
            <li class="item"><a href="#" title="Link">Link</a>
                <span class="m-desc">
                    <img src="../home.png" width="65" height="60" />
                    <p>This is a description: Four</p>
                </span>
            </li>
        </ul>
                    <img src="images/dottedline.png" width="3" height="120" />
                        <div class="right">
                            <img src="images/home.png" width="65" height="60" />
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing consectetur adipi Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur</p>
            </div>
    </div>
</li>
</ul>
```

The effect I'm after is as follows: 
on hover over `ul.menu .item` replace the contents of `.right` with `.m-desc`. Of course as there are multiple `.right` and `.m-dec` elements, I'm trying just to reference the correct 'nearest' ones rather than all. What I have so far is:

```
jQuery(function($) {
$('ul.menu .item').hover(function(){

    $(this).closest('ul').next('.right').html($(this).children('.m-desc').html());
},function(){});
});
```

The bit `$(this).children('.m-desc').html()` is referencing correctly. I can't get the traversing right for this bit though: `$(this).closest('ul').next('.right').html()`.

`$(this).closest('ul')` is pulling correctly, but when I try to add the `.next('.right')` it's having none of it.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where are the `.right` classes in the HTML code?

Comment: apologies - my ability to copy & paste has failed me. updated above. hte `.right` comes following the `ul.left`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(this).closest('ul').nextAll('.right:first').html()
```

`.next('.something')` will only select the next sibling if it matches the selector you've specified. It doesn't look like `.right` is next, so you're getting nothing. [`.nextAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/nextAll/) selects all the following siblings, which you then reduce to those with class `right`. [`:first`](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/) then selects just the first of those (ensuring at most one selected element).

Comment: excellent. works perfectly. I knew it would be something simple I was missing! :)

Answer (score 0):

From the [jQuery docs on .next()](http://api.jquery.com/next/):

> Get the immediately following sibling of each element in the set of matched elements. If a selector is provided, it retrieves the next sibling only if it matches that selector.

Try using [.find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/) instead.